# is dvmStartup called every time an app is launched

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

I added some code print messages to logcat inside dvmStartup(), but it doesn't seem to print out anything. So does dvmStartup() invoked everytime? Is it related to whether the app is started in Zygote mode or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dvmStartup is executed once when the zygote process starts. All other dalvik processes are then created by forking the zygote process.

Comment: I registered a callback function f (gDvm.shutdownHook=f) in dvmStartup, and call it in dvmShutdown ( (*gDvm.shutdownHook)() ). Does that sound like a right way to implement a "vm shutdown" hook?